# Verdaccio with LDAP authenthication

Tags: authentication, npm, verdaccio

I will like to ask if anyone has tried to auth. LDAP with verdaccio am running 5.19.0 on docker container default auth. works

```
htpasswd:
  file: ./htpasswd
```

but i try getting plugins for verdaccio auth for ldap but not working have been stop here for over a month

i need a plugins to add to the verdaccio 5.19.0 with ldap

here is my config.yaml file on docker

```
storage: /verdaccio/storage
plugins: /verdaccio/plugins
web:
  title: Verdaccio
auth:
  htpasswd:
    file: ./htpasswd
uplinks:
  npmjs:
    url: https://registry.npmjs.org/                                
packages:
  '@*/*':
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    unpublish: $authenticated
    proxy: npmjs
  '**':
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    unpublish: $authenticated
    proxy: npmjs
middlewares:
  audit:
    enabled: true
logs:
  - {type: stdout, format: pretty, level: http}
```

dockerfile

```
FROM verdaccio/verdaccio:latest

RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
RUN npm i
RUN npm i verdaccio-ldap
RUN npm i verdaccio-activedirectory -g
RUN npm i sinopia-memory -g
```

i need to auth verdaccio with ldap?

Comment: verdaccio-ldap plugin not found. try "npm install verdaccio-ldap" have try  npm install verdaccio-ldap

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read our blog

https://verdaccio.org/blog/2019/10/05/verdaccio-4-with-ldap-and-docker

and this example is outdated but might work fine with v5

https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/tree/master/docker-examples/v4/ldap-verdaccio

Comment: This help....but am trying to add user to the verdaccio with npm adduser --registry http://localhost:4873  Web login not supported ? what is wrong here

Comment: not sure what's your issue, but if you are using npm9 probably this https://verdaccio.org/docs/setup-npm#npm-login-with-npm9-or-higher if you want to add LDAP users with npm adduser plugin I think you cannot but never tried.

Comment: the issue i was not able to add user using the npm, those not support web login not supported. i will look into the link you sent me thanks for your help, yes am using npm9